# How can I do Reverse Geocoding on my own Server?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

We are getting a lot of data and are trying to build a system on our database which can convert latitude-longitude information to city and country. We don't want to use any of the google Api's. We want to set our own server to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim). It is a popular service for OpenStreetMap capable of answering geocoding and reverse-geocoding queries. It is also possible to [set up your own Nominatim instance](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim/Installation). If you want to use a public instance instead then make sure to comply with OSM's [Nominatim usage policy](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim_usage_policy) because the server runs on donated ressources. Alternatively you can use another public instance, for example the [Nominatim instance provided by MapQuest](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/open/nominatim).

Answer (score 4):

If you plan to do a do-it-yourself on a server, the simplest way I would recommend is to use a FREE database of cities that include a latitude/longitude of the city's area centroid. Import the dataset into your own database.

You can then do a distance check (query) between your point and the area centroid looking for the city centroid the point is closest to. Just remember for performance purposes:

1. Store the cities latitude/longitude as a geospatial POINT() datatype (not as a decimal!)
2. Create a geospatial index for the field that has the POINT() value for the city center.

If you use MySQL, there are a lot of answers in stackoverflow on how to do this (just search):

Here are some FREE datasets:

MaxMind: http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

Geonames.Org: http://www.geonames.org/export/

OpenGeoCode.Org (I am a co-founder of this open data project): http://www.opengeocode.org/download.php#cities

Answer (score 0):

You should setup your own Nominatim server, you can find step by step instruction here
http://nominatim.org/release-docs/latest/admin/Installation/

or

https://gist.github.com/malkitsingh/737ea34abec5b079a84dd39e3b0dc2d2

**but for this you will need strong server with lot of space.**